# Iterating through excel files and capturing a specific cell value in each file

Tags: python, excel

I have a directory of participation forms (as excel files) from clients, and I want to write a script that will grab all of the relevant cells from the participation form and write them to an excel doc where each client is on its own row. When I try and iterate through the directory using the following code:

```
import os
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import easyxf
import pandas as pd
from pandas import np
import csv

for i in os.listdir("filepath"):
    book=xlrd.open_workbook("filepath",i)
    print book
    sheet=book.sheet_by_index(0)
    a1=sheet.cell_value(rowx=8, colx=3)
    print a1
```

I get the error: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'filepath'

**EDIT Here is the Full Traceback after making edits suggested by  Steven Rumbalski**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\participation_form.py", line 11, in <module>
    book=xlrd.open_workbook(("Y:/Directory1/Directory2/Signup/", i))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 394, in open_workbook
    f = open(filename, "rb")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

Comment: Do you have the literal `"filepath"` in your code?  If so, you need to supply an actual path.  Something like `"C:/users/someone/whatever/"` or `"/home/someone/whatever/"`.

Comment: No, I have replaced my actual directory name in order to make things simpler. The file path looks like Y:\This\Is\Example

Comment: It looks like you are trying to open the folder and not the file. You need to join the filepath and the filename.  Do `book = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join("filepath", i))`.  Does that fix your problem?

Comment: Now I get the error "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found"

Comment: Do you get the error on the same line or on a different line?

Comment: The same line. Thanks for your help with this by the way!

Comment: Please put the full traceback into your question.  The traceback starts with the word "Traceback" and ends with your error message.

Comment: Your traceback shows you are passing a tuple:  `book=xlrd.open_workbook(("Y:/Directory1/Directory2/Signup/", i))`.  Change that to `book=xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join("Y:/Directory1/Directory2/Signup/", i))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlrd.open_workbook` expects its first argument to be a full path to a file.  You are trying to open the folder and not the file. You need to join the filepath and the filename. Do

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join("filepath", i))
```

You also my want to guard against trying to open things that are not excel files.  You could add this as the first line of your loop:

```
if not i.endswith((".xls", ".xlsx")): continue
```

Comment: Can you open 'Y:/Surveys/Parents/Signup/test' manually?  Do you have permissions to it?  Or perhaps is `test` a directory?

Comment: Never mind! I figured out that I was pointing at the wrong directory! I have it all sorted now. Thank you for your patience and for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify all of this with the glob module and the .read_excel() method in pandas (which you already seem to be importing). The following iterates over all the files in some directory that match "*.xlsx", parses them into data frames, and prints out the contents of the appropriate cell.

```
from glob import glob
for f in glob("/my/path/to/files/*.xlsx"):
    print pd.read_excel(f).ix[8,3]
```